# CSS Transform rotate content "jumps"

Tags: css, animation, rotation

I'm trying to modify an animation loader to my needs - on the way of modification i'm struggeling with the fact that the dice points "jumps" - it has something to do with the degrees setup of the dice itself inside the animation but i'm sitting here now 2h starring at this css code and cant figure out what might be the issue.

```
@keyframes cssload-animate {
    17% {
        border-bottom-right-radius: @border-radius;
    }
    25% {
        transform:  rotate(22.5deg);
    }
    50% {
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        border-bottom-right-radius: 39px;
    }
    75% {
        transform: rotate(76.5deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform:  rotate(90deg);
    }
}
```

See my Pen here: https://codepen.io/Proximate/pen/XWVLzNE

in the last rotation step the content (dots) jumps back you can see it when 2,  3 and 6 dots are visible. but also with the others (because the placement if the dots its not fully ok at the moment)

can someone explain to me why the content inside the dice "jumps" / rotates to the right?

Comment: You need to complete a full rotation to avoid the jump, go to 360deg and not only 90deg ... the content of your dice is not always symmetric on one axis

Comment: ok got that - it was required to do so because of the animation (jumps also upd and down on the edge) but i think i've found now an alternative look i could use